# what is the way to generate checksum for images in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How to generate checksum for images in alfresco? I have requirement to compare the images stored in alfresco between two system.

Comment: You might find interresting things here : https://github.com/Gagravarr/AlfrescoDocumentChecksums

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can store one more metadata on image node as checksum value.
For generating checksum I don't think so Alfresco OOTB has any service.
Probably you can use any algorithm you like for generating checksum in java and then generated checksum value you can store on image node using Node Service in Alfresco.